# Depth map from bumblebee2 camera?

Tags: ros, stere-image-proc, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to get the coordinates in space (X,Y,Z) of an object. For this, I am detecting the object using the image from the bumblebee's left camera (from here I can obtain the X and Y coordinates), and would like to obtain the Z-coordinate. I have the code for doing this with an Asus Xtion, but this uses a depth map. Can I get a depth map as well from my bumblebee2 camera? Or should I just use the disparity image I get from stereo_image_proc?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108526/depth-map-from-bumblebee2-camera?/) by [sofiad](https://answers.ros.org/users/8786/sofiad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2014-01-04**:
You probably want to use the points2 data type

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2016-06-21**:
Did you solve the problem? As i kown, There exist a package called"stereo_image_proc" which publish the disparity, and the "stereo_image_proc" package have a file "point_cloud2.cpp" you can get the depth of z in it(or need some transform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you manage to solve it?
I am in the same situation... would like to get the depth image but stereo_image_proc is only giving the disparity one. The transformation is easy (Z=T*f/d) , but I suppose there must be any node that implement this, and gives values or interpolate the value of the disparity nan, 0 and inf pixels....

---

Originally posted by [vvaquero](https://answers.ros.org/users/18081/vvaquero/) with karma: 46 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2014-05-16**:
(+1 for karma)